# I wrote a small web scrape script and i need help automating it

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

I've been learning Python for a couple weeks and i wanted to write a script that would automate a very tedious task i have to do for my work where i basically have to scour through a directory of over 2000 Charities in my city and get some info and make an Excel sheet out of it. [Here's what i've got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ4uJ.png)

'Book3.xlsx' contains a list of URL's that i'd scraped with a different script. The script above accesses the link, scrapes the information i want and saves it in 'Book4.xlsx'. But as you can see if can it just one at a time.

I've been struggling to automate it. Have tried (with my very limited knowledge) loops, defining a function of the above script and looping it etc but no cigar as of yet.

Any help, tips etc would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the .cell() method ? I'm not an openpyxl expert, but this could work using a `for` loop :

```
#
# You load your sheets
#

# You make your 'for' loop as long as you want in order to go over every URL in 'Book3.xslx'
for i in range(2, 11):
    source = requests.get(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value).text

    #
    # You select the info you want
    #

    outputsheet.cell(row=i, column=1) = name
    outputsheet.cell(row=i, column=2) = mobile + " " + phone
    outputsheet.cell(row=i, column=3) = email
    outputsheet.cell(row=i, column=4) = website

outputwb.save("Book4.xslx")
```

EDIT : you would have to stock all the URLs in the first column of "Book3.xslx" (column A), and the output would be, for each URL, written in a different row (1, 2, 3, etc.). Here in this particular exemple, there is only 8 URLs (from line 2 to 10 (including 10)).

Comment: Thank You!. The for loop worked when i used the  .cell() method. Although i think i made it harder for myself by trying to save it to a new xslx sheet instead of the same one. A bit of tweaking and the following code worked a treat for the output.

   name_cell = sheet.cell(row, 2)

    tele_cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)
    email_cell = sheet.cell(row, 4)
    web_cell = sheet.cell(row, 5)

    name_cell.value = name
    tele_cell.value = mobile + '     ' + phone
    email_cell.value = email
    web_cell.value = website